# this program receive numerical input and stores and when the input is 42 ,it stops receiving the inputs and prints the stored received input

Tags: c++

[image: emphasized text]

> Your program is to use the brute-force approach in order to find the Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything. More precisely… rewrite small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at input are integers of one or two digits.

Comment: Please paste the program as text. I can't see images. Also, what exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Images can't be searched, copy/pasted into compilers, or easily seen by people with visual problem. Copy/paste the actual code as text into your question. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: See `std::vector::push_back` to append items to the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the `std::vector` correctly. You are trying to read input into vector elements that do not exist yet.  You would have needed to `resize()` the vector first for that to work.  But since you don't know up front how many input values will actually be entered, you will have to instead read the input into an `int` variable first and then `push_back()` that variable into the `std::vector`.

Also, you don't need the `count` variable, you can use the `std::vector::size()` method instead.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> s;
    int input;

    while (1)
    {
        cin >> input;
        if (input == 42)
        {
            break;
        }
        s.push_back(input);
    }

    for(size_t j = 0; j < s.size(); ++j)
    {
        cout << s[j] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanku sir for your help